# regarding system used uart port of raspberrypi3 b+

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+

I want to do a serial communication Raspberrypi and voice recognition module v3, and for that I have to disable the system used UART port raspberrypi3. After disabling the raspberrypi3 b+ system used UART pot can we able to communicate with inbuilt Bluetooth as before at the same time?

Comment: what makes you think the UART port has anything to do with Bluetooth?

Comment: "disable the system used UART port" **WHY??** It is not enabled by default

Comment: ttyAMA0 port is enable by default only for system used Bluetooth\wireless communication ttyS0 is not enable ,we have to enable this port.

Comment: ttyAMAO port is enable by default only for system use Bluetooth /wireless  you can see in most of the new Raspberrypi3 b+  and ttyS0 wehave to enable ,(but I got recent new raspberrypi 3b+ it was came with enable ttyS0 )

Comment: why I want to disable the ttyAMA0 port for bluetooth..the issue with mini UART controller is that its baud rate is linked to the VPU core frequency so as the VPU frequency changes depending on processor load so does the baud rate of the UART controller.

Comment: **DO NOT post detail into Comments** - these are mostly incorrect - the default UART is `/dev/serial0` and works regardless of CPU frequency. See [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 , Pi3B+, PiZeroW](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

Comment: https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/kb/article/1035/raspberry-pi-3-serial-port-usage

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use Bluetooth and a UART at the same time on the Pi3B.

The full UART is used to talk to the Bluetooth module on the Pi3B.  That still leaves the mini UART available.  Fortunately the mini UART uses the same GPIO/pins (as the full UART).

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=155963

In particular see

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=155559#p1017172

and if you are interested in the detail

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=151454#p993901

Comment: BUT THE PROBLEM IS I AM FACING NOW IS THAT TTYS0 RELIABLE FOR GOOD SERIAL DATA COMMUNICATION.? ALSO AFTER ENABLING TTYSO IT IS NOT ABLE TO  LISTEN DATA FROM VOICE RECOGNITION MODULE V3.